# How to logging Akka Remote Actor connection is available or not?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, guice, actor

I'm using Remote Actor and trying to achieve logging When...

- A connection to the remote server is established.
- The established connection is disconnected.

And hopefully, I would like to give a random Id every time Actor tries to reestablish.
My attempt is below.

```
class SampleActor @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val remote = context.actorSelection(s"akka.tcp://PathToRemoteActor")
  val initialIdentifyId = getNextId
  remote ! Identify(initialIdentifyId)

  def receive = establish(initialIdentifyId)

  def doIdentify(nextId: Int) = {
    context become establish(nextId)
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) { remote ! Identify(nextId) }
  }

  def getNextId = new Random().nextInt(10000)

  def establish(identifyId: Int): Actor.Receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, Some(ref)) ⇒
      log.info(s"Connection to Remote Actor established with identifyId: $identifyId")
      context.watch(ref)
      context.become(active(identifyId, ref))
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, None) ⇒
      log.info(s"Connecting to Remote Actor failed. identifyId: $identifyId")
      doIdentify(getNextId)

    case foo:Foo ⇒ //do something
  }

  def active(identifyId: Int, remoteRef: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case Terminated(`remoteRef`) ⇒
      context.unwatch(remoteRef)
      log.error(s"Remote Actor was disconnected. identifyId: $identifyId")
      doIdentify(getNextId)
    case foo:Foo => //do something with the remote actor.
  }
}
```

code above is client side of remote actor.

This works as I expected except that a line `system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) { remote ! Identify(nextId) }` seems triggering some sort of heartbeat connecting implicitly.

If I keep shutting down the remote actor for while and then start running it and then shutting down once again after while. akka debug log would be something like below.

```
[warn] a.r.ReliableDeliverySupervisor - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://foo-remote@127.0.0.1:2552] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
[info] a.r.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef - Message [akka.remote.RemoteWatcher$Heartbeat$] from Actor[akka://foo-client/system/remote-watcher#1679701185] to Actor[akka://foo-client/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[info] a.r.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef - Message [akka.remote.RemoteWatcher$Heartbeat$] from Actor[akka://foo-client/system/remote-watcher#1679701185] to Actor[akka://foo-client/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[info] a.r.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef - Message [akka.remote.RemoteWatcher$Heartbeat$] from Actor[akka://foo-client/system/remote-watcher#1679701185] to Actor[akka://foo-client/deadLetters] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[info] a.r.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef - Message [akka.remote.RemoteWatcher$Heartbeat$] from Actor[akka://foo-client/system/remote-watcher#1679701185] to Actor[akka://foo-client/deadLetters] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[info] a.r.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef - Message [akka.remote.RemoteWatcher$Heartbeat$] from Actor[akka://foo-client/system/remote-watcher#1679701185] to Actor[akka://foo-client/deadLetters] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
...
```

If I remove the line `system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) { remote ! Identify(nextId) }`, only one heart beat dead letter log is produced.

How Can I avoid the multiple heartbeat?
maybe the way I use `Identify(nextId)` is wrong?

Thanks in advance.